# Почему rust не может обработать цепочку итераторов, переданных по ссылке?

Tags: rust, итераторы, traits

Хочу сделать функцию, которая степит итератор и при не удаче, восстанавливает его в исходное состояние, возвращая сообщение об ошибке. Важно, что итератор передается по мутабельной ссылке, так-как он потом будет нужен для дальнейшей обработки.

Собсна сабж в том, что при создании цепочки итераторов, в котором первый передается по ссылке, rust требует, чтобы у него был заиплеменчен трейт Clone. Почему?

```rust
use std::str::Chars;

fn next_or_restore<T: Iterator + Clone>(it: &mut T, msg: String) -> Result<T::Item, String> {
    let tmp = (*it).clone();

    match it.next() {
        Some(v) => Ok(v),
        None => {
            *it = tmp;
            Err(msg)
        }
    }
}

fn my_parser(it: &mut Chars) -> Result<String, String> {
    let ch = next_or_restore(
        &mut it.take(3),
        "some parsing error...".into()
    )?;

    // just a stub for test here
    Ok(ch.to_string())
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = "test123Test".chars();
    my_parser(&mut a).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8768deb1b9300b9cb39b91974e07c181

Comment: Как оно должно "восстанавливает его в исходное состояние" при невозможности клонировать?

Answer (score 0):

> rust требует, чтобы у него был заиплеменчен трейт Clone. Почему?

Вы же сами в коде вызываете `.clone()`, который может присутствовать только у типа, который имплементит `Clone`.

Цель понятна, и ваше решение вполне очевидно - вы делаете бекап итератора в `tmp` (хотя я бы назвал его `bkp`), и потом восстанавливаетесь из него, но тогда требование к наличию `Clone` тоже вполне закономерно.

Вы, наверное, заметили из подсказок компилятора что:

```
= note: `Clone` is implemented for `&std::str::Chars<'_>`, but not for `&mut std::str::Chars<'_>`
```

Т.е. если бы ссылка была не мутабельная, то все было бы впорядке, т.к. `Clone` уже имплементирован. Но для мутабельной он не имплементирован. Это связано с основными принципами Раста - может быть либо несколько немутабельных ссылок, либо одна мутабельная. Отсюда следует, что вы не можете просто так взять, и склонировать итератор по мутабельной ссылке. Если вам так нужна именно копия итератора, то либо придется вручную проходиться по всем элементам и копировать их, создавая новый итератор, или искать другие пути.

Но есть и другие варианты, например использовать `.inspect()`, который позволит посмотреть что там с элементами, не меняя состояния. Но самое простое, наверное, использовать [`.peekable()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable), который нужен как раз для этого - проверить следующий элемент, перед тем как использовать `.next()`:

```rust
fn next_or_restore<T: Iterator>(it: &mut T, msg: String) -> Result<T::Item, String> {
    let mut tmp = it.peekable();

    match tmp.peek() {
        Some(_) => {
            Ok(tmp.next().unwrap())
        },
        None => {
            Err(msg)
        }
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b33a3a11d8adcef333b831eac22f2d47)